# 0 = (select count(h.id_h) from House h where h.id_h = lp.id_h AND h.id_none = '1') meaning?

Tags: sql

I have this query:

```
select lp.id_line
from Line lp,
     Enter eta 
WHERE lp.date_line <= sysdate
  AND lp.status = 10 
  AND 0 = (select count(h.id_h) from House h where h.id_h = lp.id_h AND h.id_none = '1') 
  AND lp.et_code = eta.et_code
  AND (eta.et_block <> '1' or eta.et_block is null)
  and eta.par_code In ('DC46004');
```

However I don't understand what the part:

```
AND 0 = (select count(h.id_h) from House h where h.id_h = lp.id_h AND h.id_none = '1')
```

does. 
The line

```
select count(h.id_h) from House h where h.id_h = lp.id_h AND h.id_none = '1'
```

returns 7 as result.
Please help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
AND 0 = (select count(h.id_h) from House h
  WHERE h.id_h = lp.id_h
  AND h.id_none = '1')
```

Is semantically equivalent to:

```
AND NOT EXISTS (select * from House h
 WHERE h.id_h = lp.id_h
 AND h.id_none = '1')
```

By the way, this is a correlated subquery, which executes once for every row in Line. Some optimuzer will convert it to s join, but if they don't it will perform badly.

It would be better to convert this query to only use (proper) joins.

Answer (score 0):

You won't get any results unless the inner query returns zero. For example the below query will returns second highest value if you want you can change to 3 for third highest value, the below query will give some idea for you.

```
SELECT a.sal
FROM emp a
WHERE 2 = (SELECT (COUNT(DISTINCT(sal))) FROM emp b WHERE a.sal <= b.sal)
```

~Temruzinn

Comment: Just a note, `DISTINCT` is not a function! I.e. you're actually doing `COUNT(DISTINCT sal)`.